# How can I prevent a user from saving a record with a null value?

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms

I'm very new to database programming and I've got a small database (SQL CE 3.5). It has a "LastName" column that doesn't accept nulls. I'm using the BindingNavigator to get around. Do I have to set an event similar to below for every control on that navigator. Or is there an easier way around it?

I'm using C# with .NET 3.5 and WinForms. This is also just a single table db.

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastNameTextBox.Text))

        {
            this.Validate();
            this.tblMembersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.dataSet1);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Last Name Field cannot be empty");
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: An empty string is completely different from a null value...

Comment: Are you talking DB or Application level??

Comment: C#? VB? Entity framework? .NET 4? .NET 3.5? ASP.NET? Silverlight? I think you need to specify them.

Comment: You can set TextBox = null and still have it displayed on the form. You also can't force the text of TextBox to be null, it will always be return as an empty string. In it's current form this question does not make sense.

Comment: OK, I added a code sample. I hope it makes things clearer. I apologize for my inexperience.

Comment: Add a `CHECK` constraint to disallow an empty string (retain the `NOT NULL` declaration too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could do it.

The first would be in your SQL code. You could use 
`isnull(lastname, 'something')` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

Or you could give the column a default value in the database -

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD CONSTRAINT
Name_of_Constraint DEFAULT 'value' FOR column_name
```

That work for you?

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking into your second suggestion now.

Answer (score 2):

You should really be using:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastNameTextBox.Text))
{
  ...
}
```

Also, why not just use the RequiredFieldValidator to ensure that the form can't be posted back without a value in that field?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx

Comment: This isn't a WebForm. Is there something similar for WinForms? I do like the IF condition though. Much more thorough.